# How can I solve XDE Exit Code: HypervisorNotRunning (13) when installing a VS android emulator?

Tags: visual-studio, android-emulator

I have the following error while trying to install a VS android emulator:

```
[Critical] An error occured while creating 'VS Emulator 5" Lollipop (5.0) XXHDPI Phone' device.
[Critical] XDE Exit Code: HypervisorNotRunning (13)
```

Does someone know how to fix this?

Comment: question in not clear

Comment: Try working through the [Troubleshooting the Visual Studio Emulator for Android](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt228282.aspx) guide.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure Visual Studio can start Hyper-V properly by using this command (in elevated mode) :

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

That was the issue for me, but there might be other causes to the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the visual studio android emulator and the visual studio as an admin. For me, it worked.